# Entfällt der Artikel, wenn wir eine Zahl hinter einem Nomen haben?

Tags: grammaticality, article

Wir betrachten die folgenden Sätze:

> Der Zug nach Hamburg fährt von Gleis 3.
>
> In einem Hauptsatz steht das Verb auf Position 2.

In beiden Sätzen entfallen die Artikel der Nomen, denen eine Zahl folgt.

Entfällt der Artikel, immer wenn wir eine Zahl hinter einem Nomen haben? Sagt man z.B.

> Wir haben Lektion 3 beendet.

oder ist der folgende Satz auch richtig?

> Wir haben *die* Lektion 3 beendet.

Comment: "In beiden Sätzen entfallen die Artikel der Nomen, denen eine Zahl folgt." - Denn in beiden Sätzen sind je zwei Artikel drin - für die anderen Nomen :) ("entfallen" statt "fallen ... aus" wäre ein anderes Thema)

Comment: "Wir haben *die* Lektion 3 beendet." (Betonung auf *die*) würde ich nur sagen, wenn ich betonen wollte, dass es gerade diese Lektion war und es eine besondere Leistung ist, diese Lektion beendet zu haben (z.B. weil sie für ihren Schwierigkeitsgrad berüchtigt ist). Dasselbe im Beispiel mit dem Gleis: "Der Zug fährt von *dem* [berühmten] Gleis 3 ab."

Comment: @Roland Auch möglich wäre "die Lektion 3" auch im Gegensatz zu einer anderen. Vielleicht wurde das Buch überarbeitet und eine andere Lektion an dritte Stelle gelegt. Nun hat aber der Lehrer noch die alte Lektion gelehrt und der Vertretung wird erklärt, dass die Klasse "die Lektion 3" gemacht hat, nicht die andere.

Comment: Speziell im Süddeutschen findet man die Form "die Lektion" in der Umgangssprache häufiger. Im Schriftlichen klingt es eher ungelenk, außer man will wirklich die "3" dabei betonen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nummerierte Dinge können grammatikalisch wie Eigennamen behandelt werden. In dem Fall hat man einen abweichenden Gebrauch des Artikels und lässt ihn in den oben genannten Beispielen entsprechend weg.

Es ist aber nicht notwendigerweise so, d.h. der Artikel kann auch wie gewohnt verwendet werden. Die Bedeutung des Satzes ändert sich damit nicht. Es ist aber möglich, über die Betonung des Artikels das zur speziellen Hervorhebung zu nutzen.